# Not able to kill service when android restarts it for first time using stopself(startId)?

Tags: android

Initially i'm removing the app from application tray and Android restarts using

```
     public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        /* some work */
        return START_REDELIVER_INTENT;
        }
```

After android restarts i resume my work and,
then at some place i'm calling

```
    boolean state = stopSelfResult(msg.arg1);
```

In logs 'state' is false.But both 'startId' and 'msg.arg1' are same.